# Picocli - java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, command-line, picocli

```
@Parameters(index = "0")
private Double min_c_re;

@Parameters(index = "1")
private Double min_c_im;

@Parameters(index = "2")
private Double max_c_re;

@Parameters(index = "3")
private Double max_c_im;

@Parameters(index = "4")
private Integer max_n;

@Parameters(index = "5")
private Integer width;

@Parameters(index = "6")
private Integer height;

@Parameters(index = "7")
private Integer divisions;

@Parameters(index = "8", arity = "1..*")
private List<URL> hosts;

@Override
public void run() {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    List<SubDivider.SubDivision> subDividedImages = new SubDivider(divisions, divisions).divide(image);

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    double realRange = max_c_re - min_c_re;
    double imaginaryRange = max_c_im - min_c_im;

    for (int i = 0; i < subDividedImages.size(); i++) {
        SubDivider.SubDivision subDivision = subDividedImages.get(i);
        BufferedImage subDividedImage = subDivision.getImage();
        URL host = hosts.get(i % hosts.size());

        double xPercent = subDivision.getOriginalMinX() / (double) width;
        double yPercent = subDivision.getOriginalMinY() / (double) height;
        double widthPercent = subDividedImage.getWidth() / (double) width;
        double heightPercent = subDividedImage.getHeight() / (double) height;

        String resource = new StringJoiner("/")
                             .add("/mandelbrot")
                             .add(Double.toString(min_c_re + realRange * xPercent))
                             .add(Double.toString(min_c_im + imaginaryRange * yPercent))
                             .add(Double.toString(min_c_re + realRange * xPercent + realRange * widthPercent))
                             .add(Double.toString(min_c_im + imaginaryRange * yPercent + imaginaryRange * heightPercent))
                             .add(Integer.toString(subDividedImage.getWidth()))
                             .add(Integer.toString(subDividedImage.getHeight()))
                             .add(Integer.toString(max_n))
                             .toString();

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(host, resource);
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " +
                               exception.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        threadPool.submit(new SubDivisionGenerator(url, subDividedImage));
    }

    try {
        threadPool.shutdown();
        threadPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
        System.err.println("Exception: "
                           + exception.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    File file = new File("output.pgm");
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

    try {
        Imaging.writeImage(image, file, ImageFormats.PGM, params);
    } catch (ImageWriteException | IOException exception) {
        System.err.println("Exception: "
                           + exception.getMessage());
        return;
    }
}
```

When I run the command `java -jar target/cli-1.0.0.jar -1 -1.5 2 1.5 1024 10000 10000 4 http://localhost:8080`

I get this exception:

```
Could not convert 'https://localhost:8080' to Integer for positional parameter at index 6 (<height>): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "https://localhost:8080"
```

picocli version 2.3.0 is used

Comment: Mixage, is there any reason to stay on this very old version of picocli? The latest version has many bug fixes and new features. (FYI, upgrading won’t make a help solve the question you asked; I would recommend Per Huss’s answer to use `setUnmatchedOptionsArePositionalParams` to tell the picocli parser what to do with [unmatched options](https://picocli.info/#_unknown_options) for that.)

Comment: FYI, I added [showing the `--` end-of-options delimiter in the usage help message](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/985) to the roadmap for picocli 4.3. I do like @per-huss's suggestion to use `setUnmatchedOptionsArePositionalParams` because it does not rely on the end users' understanding of the `--` end-of-options delimiter; it means your application will "just work" for most users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dash in the negative numbers make them look like options. Try using the flag:

```
CommandLine.setUnmatchedOptionsArePositionalParams(true)
```

Comment: @RemkoPopma Is this how i should solve the problem?

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int exitCode = new CommandLine(new ImageGenerator()).setUnmatchedOptionsArePositionalParams(true).execute(args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
 }

Answer (score 5):

Try double dash https://picocli.info/#_double_dash:

```
java -jar target/cli-1.0.0.jar -- -1 -1.5 2 1.5 1024 10000 10000 4 http://localhost:8080
```

negative numbers can not be passed directly on the command line. They have not been recognized as positional parameters, therefore it is saying that your url is at position 6

Comment: Thanks for helping, I get this error now
Could not convert '--' to Double for positional parameter at index 1 (<min_c_im>): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "--"

Comment: @Mixage read 3.8 from documentation https://picocli.info/#_negatable_options. double dash. It may be I have misstyped the syntax.

Comment: @Mixage  the point is that when you specify only one dash it interprets it as option and not as positional parameter.

Comment: I got it. You were right. I removed negative parameters and it worked.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov I believe you intended to link to the “end-of-options” delimiter `--` [section of the manual](https://picocli.info/#_double_dash) instead of Negatable Options.

Comment: @RemkoPopma thanks that is exactly what i wanted to post.